# Python code does not come out when first return statement is executed

Tags: python-3.x, return-value

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rhodZ.png)I am a begineer in Python development and learning python on python 3.6
When I executed below code ,I expected it to terminate when first return statement is executed and I was expecting Output 4.
But It is iterating 3 times and giving output as 8.

As per my understanding as soon as return statement is executed it should come out of the function. Why this is not happening.

```py
#!/bin/python3


def stockmax(prices):
    # Write your code here
    # Write your code here
    count=0
    profit=0
    maximum=max(prices)
    #print(maximum)
    index_max=prices.index(maximum)
    #print(index_max)
    if len(prices)<=1:
        return(profit)
    else:
        for i in range(len(prices)):
            if i<index_max:
                profit=profit-prices[i]
                #print("profit if",profit)
                count=count+1
                #print("count is",count)
            elif i==index_max:
                #print(profit)
                profit=profit+(prices[i]*count)
                #print("profit elif",profit)
                count=0
            else:
                profit=profit+stockmax(prices[i:])
                
    return(profit)  # should terminate on executing first return


x=(stockmax([5,4,3,4,5]))
print(x)
```

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Can you please [edit] your question to clarify why you did not expect the repetitions? ``stockmax`` includes a ``for`` loop and is recursive, so it is made to repeat. Is this your own code or did you get it from someone else?

Answer (score 0):

By calling `stockmax` inside of itself, you are opening up a new 'scope'. We can treat these as levels on a building. When you call it, you are essentially moving up a floor, or gaining a level. To get back to the ground floor, or the main 'scope' you need to go back through all of the lower floors. We can do this easily by using `return` a little bit sooner. In your code it would look a little like this:

```py
def stockmax(prices):
    count=0
    profit=0
    maximum=max(prices)
    index_max=prices.index(maximum)
    if len(prices)<=1:
        return(profit)
    else:
        for i in range(len(prices)):
            if i<index_max:
                profit=profit-prices[i]
                count=count+1
            elif i==index_max:
                profit=profit+(prices[i]*count)
                count=0
            else:
                profit=profit+stockmax(prices[i:])
                return(profit)  # Use return here instead!
```

This would give us the desired output of 4.